# .NET custom form. Inherit in another class with form border

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Sorry for the bad title, is hard to describe what i need.

I created a WinForm, set the BorderStyle to none, and i draw the entire form on the OnPaint().

I did this to use this custom form, several times in my application with a custom UI.

This was fine.

After that i created a new WinForm, but instead of inherit the System.Windows.Foms.Fom, i inherited my custom class.

This works perfectly.

No what i need to do:

In the Visual Studio IDE, when i create a form based in my custom form, and I'm dragging components from the toolbox, the components overlap the border of the form.

For example, if i add a MenuStrip, it's placed above the border of my form and not bellow as it would if the form was a System.Windows.Forms.Form.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your form's Padding property in the designer, something equivalent to:

```
this.Padding = new Padding(borderWidth);
```

It won't prevent controls from entering your customer border space, but controls that have their docking property set, like the MenuStrip control, will adhere to that padding space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the problem, but you might try creating a UserControl instead of a custom form. You can design the user control much like a form, then place it in other forms as a control.

Comment: It's hard to explain. But basically, i changed the Border of the form, to match the skin create for my UI. The main difference in the form that i created, is the caption bar, and the 3 buttons (minimize, maximize and close).

Comment: For example, Google Chrome or Firefox uses a custom form border, it's not the windows default one.